competing risk analysis in R using tidycmprsk, timereg, or riskRegression package
I am conducting a competing risk analysis using the Melanoma data from the {MASS} package but have been unable to obtain consistent results across the following three packages: tidycmprsk, timereg, and riskRegression.
Please note that I have modified the status code in the dataset according to the website below.
https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html#Cumulative_incidence_for_competing_risks
Melanoma <- 
  Melanoma %>% 
  mutate(
    status = as.factor(recode(status, `2` = 0, `1` = 1, `3` = 2))
  )

The codes I tried are as follows. All the codes seem to work, but they yield different results. Could you tell me how I should correct the codes in the comp.risk and riskRegression parts to yield the same results as the crr part?

crr() function from the {tidycmprsk} package

crr(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + age, data = Melanoma)
## 
## Variable   Coef    SE      HR     95% CI       p-value    
## sex        0.588   0.272   1.80   1.06, 3.07   0.030      
## age        0.013   0.009   1.01   0.99, 1.03   0.18


comp.risk() function from the {timereg} package

fit_comprisk <- comp.risk(Event(time, status, cens.code=0) ~ const(sex) + const(age),
                          data = Melanoma, cause = 1, model = "prop")
summary(fit_comprisk)
## Competing risks Model 
## 
## No test for non-parametric terms
## Parametric terms : 
##                Coef.      SE Robust SE      z P-val lower2.5% upper97.5%
## const(sex) -0.394000 0.20200   0.20200 -1.950 0.051   -0.7900    0.00191
## const(age)  0.000604 0.00557   0.00557  0.108 0.914   -0.0103    0.01150


riskRegression() function from the {riskRegression} package

fit_rskreg <- riskRegression(Hist(time, status, cens.code=0) ~ sex + age,
                             data = Melanoma, cause = 1, link = "prop")
fit_rskreg
## Competing risks regression model
## 
## IPCW weights: marginal Kaplan-Meier for the censoring distribution.
## Link: 'cloglog' yielding sub-hazard ratios (Fine & Gray 1999)
## No covariates with time-varying coefficient specified.
## 
## Time constant regression coefficients:
##   Variable Levels Coef Lower Upper Pvalue
## sex        1.94 1.115  3.37 0.0189
## age        1.01 0.991  1.03 0.3306
## 
## 
## Note: The coefficients (Coef) are sub-hazard ratios (Fine & Gray 1999)


are you sure they are all using the same method for competing risk? One is using Fine & Gray but I am not sure if the others are (they could be using a multi-state model). Additionally your recoding looks a bit weird try converting status to a numeric variable with levels 0, 1 , and 2.

It seems crr() and comp.risk() with model = "prop" all use the Fine & Gray models.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cmprsk/versions/2.2-11/topics/crr
As for recoding the Melanoma data are coded in a non-standard way (1 died from melanoma, 2 alive, 3 dead from other causes) so I recoded to standardize it (0=alive, 1=died from melanoma, 2=dead from other causes).

I asked several statisticians and R geeks around me and it seems that crr from the tidycmprsk package is the one that almost everyone is using.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
